# Debugging Task.WhenAny and Push Notifications

Tags: c#, .net, azure, async-await, azure-notificationhub

I have the following snippet to handle Azure Notification Hub push notifications:

```
var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\"}}";

var task = AzurePushNotifications.Instance.Hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert, username);

if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(500)) == task)
{
     success = true;
}
```

Occasionally, this will fail - I'm trying to figure out why ?

What's the best way to get some diagnostic information when running things with `Task.WhenAny`?

I'd like to know if either an exception was thrown, or if the timeout has been hit.

Comment: What do you mean this _fails_? If it's timing out, you have only alloted 500ms for the notification, this may need to be increaed. If you `await` the notification task alone does it raise an exception? If so please post those details.

Comment: Why aren't you just awaiting the task; task.Wait();  and then looking at the TaskResult task.TaskResult?

Comment: @JSteward sometimes I get `success = false`.  This is either because it didn't complete in 500ms, or because an exception was thrown.  I want to know which one of these is happening.  If it's an exception, I want to know what the exception is.  If it takes > 500ms, I want it to fail, but I want to know that's why it failed.  Without these timeouts, the push notifications sometimes take literally forever.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII See above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have three possibilities:

1. `Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(500)) == task` is false. It means that the task timed out
2. `Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(500)) == task` is true. Then either:

   - If `t1.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion`, then the task ran successfully
   - Otherwise, it's either cancelled or faulted. Check `task.IsFaulted` and `task.Exception` to find more information

> If it takes > 500ms, I want it to fail, but I want to know that's why it failed

In that case, the only thing you can know is that the notification timed out. There is no exception to log since the task hasn't completed yet. If you want to check the status when it eventually completes, you can chain a continuation:

```
task.ContinueWith(t => 
{
    // Log t.Exception
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: While the logic is correct, I can't condone this usage of `ContinueWith`/`IsFaulted`/`Exception`. You should just use `await` instead: `await task` inside the `if` block.

Comment: @StephenCleary If we use await then it defeats the point of having a timeout in first place. The logic here is to say "ok, the task didn't answer in time so I give control back to the caller, but I chain a continuation to know what happened when the task eventually completes"

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know if either an exception was thrown, or if the timeout has been hit.

You just need to observe the completed task, as such:

```
var task = ...;
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(500)) == task)
{
  await task;
  success = true;
}
```

This will propagate the exception, allowing you to distinguish between the task failing (an exception will be thrown), the task succeeding (`success == true`), and the task timing out (`success == false`).

Comment: Thank you Stephen - did you see Kevin's comment above?  I'm trying to avoid requests taking more than 500ms (even that is ridiculous) and for some reason these calls to Notification Hub never return.  I've implemented a generous timeout to address this but I wonder - what would you recommend?

Comment: @user666: I have no experience with Notification Hub, but if you're sure you're not [blocking further up your call stack](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), then that would be an Azure tech support question.

Comment: I was asking more from a general coding perspective - if I `await` something that could never return, what's the best way to achieve what I've outlined as my goals above, and given the comment in the accepted answer?  I feel like future readers could benefit from having an answer from you here - seems like a not-quite-edge-case of async/await

Comment: @user666: You're actually [not supposed to ever do that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/02/dont-forget-to-complete-your-tasks/). A never-ending task will be a resource leak.

Comment: I'm aware of that.  But I didn't build Azure.  How would you handle this?

Comment: @user666: I would open a support ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Dude, you're missing the point.  What if this was some code that joe shmo wrote that I don't have a support channel for?  How do you leverage the framework to mitigate this?

Comment: @user666: Then I would have them fix it, or write a replacement. Code that doesn't work can't be reused. In this particular situation, *there is no proper way to handle a never-ending task*. Nothing in the framework. Nothing you can do yourself. Unless you are OK with resource leaks, in which case just use the code in my answer.

Comment: It's so odd to me that someone with as much experience as you have can't empathize with the reality that sometimes these things are out of our control.  Advising me to accept resource leaks is terrible advice.  At least the accepted answer offers a real solution!

Comment: @user666: Let me put it this way: you have a function that leaks resources, and you're asking how to prevent it from leaking resources. The only possible solutions are to *fix it* or *not use it*. I empathize, but you are asking for a logical impossibility. The accepted answer will leak resources if the task never completes.