# Task.WhenAny - A Task was Cancelled

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

In the following code:

```
        if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(100)) == task) {
            success = true;
        }
        else {
            details += "Timed out on SendGrid.";
            await task.ContinueWith(s =>
            {
                LogError(s.Exception);
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        }
```

I occasionally get `A task was cancelled` at the call to `await task.ContinueWith`.  My goal here is to see if the `task` completes within 100ms - if it doesn't, I want to handle some logging (this particular task has a resource leak so I'm trying to work around it by wrapping it in a timeout).  This is being pulled from the guidance here:  [Debugging Task.WhenAny and Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170246/debugging-task-whenany-and-push-notifications)

Why is this happening, and what can I do to prevent this exception from being thrown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when your `task` was not able to complete in time (in 100ms) BUT was able to complete later. You run your continuation with `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` and such tasks got cancelled if original task did NOT faulted. You `await` result of `ContinueWith` so if your task is not faulted - your continuation is cancelled and you have an exception.

In general such way to handle timeout does not make much sense, because even after timeout is reached you still wait until original task is completed, to log an exception. I think your have to remove `await` before your continuation. Then code will continue on timeout, but if task will fail later - it will be recorded.

There is another issue in your code - `Task.WhenAny` will never throw. So this condition:

```
await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(100)) == task
```

does NOT mean success, because `task` might be faulted. Always check `task.Status` and `task.Exception` even if `WhenAny` indicates completion of your task. By the way, that answer you linked in your question mentions this.

Update: if you don't like VS warning about not awaited call - you can either disable it for this specific line, or use extension method like this:

```
static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static void Forget(this Task task)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

And then:

```
task.ContinueWith(s => {
    Logger.Write(s.Exception);
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted).Forget();
```

There is no harm in doing this (in this particular case of course), VS just issues this warning on every potentially awaitable call which is not awaited.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear.  Given that I'm trying to handle a leaky API, how would you recommend handling this without throwing any exceptions (and just logging)?

Comment: Updated answer - just remove `await` before task.ContinueWith.

Comment: Then VS complains that I'm not awaiting an async call.

Comment: @SB2055 Updated once again.

Answer (score 0):

Task continuations are cancelled if they do not run. Your task continuation will run OnlyOnFaulted. If it doesn't fault, then the continuation will get cancelled.

Your two choices that don't involve handling that specific exception are to either not await anything (and not know if the Task has finished running or not), or to await the original Task. Once the await has finished, the task continuation will either run or get cancelled at that point.

If you're fine with handling the cancellation, then simply catch the TaskCancelledException (or AggregateException as appropriate) on the task continuation as needed and discard the exception.

The best way, in my opinion, for this specific case (logging the exception) is to just await the original task again and handle the TaskCancelledException, no task continuation needed and fully async/await compliant.